# Unable to create an object of type ApplicationDbContext that inherits from IdentityDBContext after migration to 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

When I try to add a migration after migration to **.net core 3.0 and ef core 3.0** I get the error: Unable to create an object of type 'ApplicationDbContext'.

[image]

Dependencies are as follows:

[image]

My code is as follows:

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, ILocalizationDbContext
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }        

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        : base(options)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    } 
   }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), 
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Infrastructure")), 
            ServiceLifetime.Transient);

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
    }
```

**Program.cs**

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
                {
                    webHostBuilder
          .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
          .UseIISIntegration()
          .UseStartup<Startup>();
                })
                .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the link in the error message says, update your Program class to look like this.

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args)
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }

    // EF Core uses this method at design time to access the DbContext
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
                {
                    webHostBuilder
                       .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                       .UseIISIntegration()
                       .UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
}
```